# model not working in jersey jsp

Tags: jsp, jersey

Action:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces("text/html")
public Response test()
{
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("name", "pedja1");
    return Response.ok(new Viewable("/test", map)).build();
}
```

test.jsp:
It in folder `webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi ${model.name}!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

i have this in `web.xml`:

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>/(resources|(WEB-INF/jsp))/.*</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Page gets loaded but it prints `Hi ${model.name}!`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSP 2.2 EL it keyword in Jersey Viewable - where is it documented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076829/jsp-2-2-el-it-keyword-in-jersey-viewable-where-is-it-documented)

Answer (score 0):

Here I managed to find the doc where the answer of the duplicate came from :

https://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/mvcj

> JSP support
>
> Jersey provides MVC support for JSP pages. There is a JSP template
>   processor that resolves absolute template references to processable
>   template references that are JSP pages as follows: 
>   if the absolute
>   template reference does not end in ".jsp" append it to the reference;
>   and
>
> if Servlet.getResource returns a non-null value for the appended
>   reference then return the appended reference as the processable
>   template reference otherwise return null.
>
> Thus the absolute template reference "/com/foo/Foo/index" would be
>   resolved to "/com/foo/Foo/index.jsp" if there exists the JSP page
>   "/com/foo/Foo/index.jsp" in web the application.
>
> Jersey will assign the model instance to the attribute named "it". So
>   in the case of the implicit example it is possible to access the foo
>   property on the Foo controller as follows:
>
> ${it.foo}